# How do I set the parent activity of an activity at runtime?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-navigation, up-navigation

I have an arbitrary number of hierarchically nested views/activities. The action bar should show the Up navigation button to navigate to a higher level in any view. For this, the [google documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) says I have to set the parent activity with a  tag in the activity's xml definition. However, I'm creating my activities dynamically and a child element can be of the same activity as it's parent.

So how do I set the parent activity to the actual parent instance at runtime?

Comment: another related question - real solution was comes from the comment on accepted answer: [Dynamically set parent activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184154/dynamically-set-parent-activity)

Comment: There are two ways to properly support the 'up' navigation. See my answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34775181/4839264

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you are confusing up and back navigation.

The up button should be deterministic. From a given screen, the up button should always bring the user to the same screen.

The back button should not always bring the user to the same screen. The purpose of the back button is to help the user go backwards through your app chronologically. It should bring the user to the previous screen.

If there is no clear hierarchy of screens (e.g. there are no parent/child screens), then you may not need to implement up navigation at all.

See: [Navigation with Up and Back](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html)

One option for overriding the default up button behavior is to simply intercept up button clicks and handle it yourself. For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        // Launch the correct Activity here
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: I understand the up as well as the back button. And there IS a clear hierarchy, but it's determined at runtime (based on dynamic content).

Comment: Say for example you want to make an app to create a family tree and each person would have it's own view with a photo and notes about that person. So the entry point is your grandfather, then you choose your mother, then yourself. Now you can add at runtime the profile of your son, which would create a lower node in the hierarchy. From your son, you click "up" 3 times to get back to your grandfather. How do I implement that?

Comment: I would still consider that more appropriate for the back button, but I agree that it is a gray area. I've updated my answer with an example of what you are trying to accomplish. Instead of setting the parent in XML, you can choose an action to perform when the up button is clicked.