# How can I programmatically set a parent activity in android

Tags: android, parent

Is it possible to set parent activity programmatically .  Normally I am setting parent activity from the manifest file but I need to change parent activity  dynamically .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you handle the Navbar Up Navigation manually as shown [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) then you don't need to set the Parent Activity in the Android Manifest. Do note that the method shown in the above guide has a big flaw. i.e. NavUtils behaves differently for ICS(and lower APIs) and JellyBean(and higher APIs) as explained [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14792752/238768)

Comment: another related question - also with no real answer: [How do I set the parent activity of an activity at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20378894/how-do-i-set-the-parent-activity-of-an-activity-at-runtime)