# How to Implement Up Navigation in Android for 2 parents that point to 1 child activity

Tags: android

I'd like to find out if it is possible to implement a navigation system where one child activity can have two parent activities. Basically, I have a stream of content which a user may favourite. They can share a saved item via email, from both the stream activity and an activity which displays "favourited" content. I want to avoid duplicating a class simply because of navigation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. But in case of 2 or more parents you **cant** rely on the implementation of Up Navigation as described here: [Providing Up Navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)

So, you are left with 2 options:

**1- Use the back button behavior**

You can do this by just calling `finish()` or `onBackPressed()` in your `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`'s `android.R.id.home` case. Like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        finish();
        return true;
}
```

**2- Go back to the first activity of your app**

Take the user back to first activity from where your app starts, like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        Intent backIntent = new Intent(this, YOUR_FIRST_ACTIVITY.class);
        backIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(backIntent);
        return true;
}
```

By the way, this question is a possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654357/android-up-navigation-for-an-activity-with-multiple-parents)

Comment: @sena16 plz mark my answer as correct, so that others can benefit from it also, thanks in advance :)

Comment: It's not up to you to decide whether or not your answer is correct

Comment: @TimCastelijns i know, thats why I've asked the asker to mark it as answer. Correctness of the answer is implied on the basis if it did solve the asker's problem.

Comment: Yes but you don't know if it solved the problem, so there's no valid reason to tell him to accept it

Comment: Again, i am not forcing nor i can. I can only ask and thats what I did.